# Using events to pass information to a parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a user control class that has the following behavior (pretty normal stuff)

```
public class C1 
{
    //controls with auto generated code in the designer file that I can access  
    //such as with the following action (for example)
    string s1 = txtThing.Text;
}
```

It is created (and destroyed, along with other classes) dynamically via a call in the parent form like:

```
public class MainForm
{
    UserControl activeControl = null;

    //...later on...
    activeControl = new C1(params...)  
    //later on, as a new control is needed
    panel.Controls.Clear();
}
```

I need to dynamically add an event handler to the text boxes text changed event, and the event lives in the MainForm class. So I want to do something like

```
activeControl.txtThing.TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyCustomHandler);
```

But the text box is obviously private. If I creat e property to get it (or even just the text) in the C1 class, I still cannot "get" the control pr property I need and I have no idea why... The only properties I can see (with activeControl. in intellisense) are the standard user control properties, and none of C1's properties. I'm not sure why...
Help is appreciated of course, hopefully you see what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 0):

After you created a property in the C1 class, you need to cast `activeControl`.

```
if (activeControl is C1)
    (activeControl as C1).TxtThingProperty.TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyCustomHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you! Much frustration solved (so far). Would you be able to explain quick why exactly activeControl wouldn't know it is a C1 when it is assigned?

Comment: The reason is that `activeControl` is declared as a UserControl. Even if you assigned a derived class of UserControl (like C1), you can't access to C1 members without cast `activeControl`.

Comment: This can be explained by the fact that you can assign other class which inherited of UserControl (imagine a class C2) to `activeControl` between the assignment of C1 and the event subscription. This is why Intellisense waits you to specify the type of the object with a cast, that without which the compiler can't know that activeControl is of type C1.